# How to simplify a if/else jquery snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, minify, simplify

I have a super long jquery snippet that I feel could be simplified with the right logic.  I'm afraid to touch it since I finally got it to work.

the "else $target = #none" is literally a "show nothing" statement.  I wasn't sure how to express that in a better way.

Thanks so much! -zeem

PS. links are to medical marijuana sites, so NSFW links!

```
    $(function () {
    var $target = $('#CO1');
    if (mmjsRegion == 'CO') {
        $target = $('#CO1');
    } else {
        $target = $('#none');
    }
    $target.imBannerRotater({
        return_type: 'json',
        data_map: {
            image_name: 'name',
            url_name: 'url'
        },
        image_url: 'http://www.kindreviews.com/wp-content/plugins/geoads/CO1.php',
        base_path: 'http://www.kindreviews.com/wp-content/plugins/geoads/images/',
    });
});

$(function () {
    var $target = $('#CO2');
    if (mmjsRegion == 'CO') {
        $target = $('#CO2');
    } else {
        $target = $('#none');
    }
    $target.imBannerRotater({
        return_type: 'json',
        data_map: {
            image_name: 'name',
            url_name: 'url'
        },
        image_url: 'http://www.kindreviews.com/wp-content/plugins/geoads/CO2.php',
        base_path: 'http://www.kindreviews.com/wp-content/plugins/geoads/images/',
    });
});
$(function () {
    var $target = $('#CO3');
    if (mmjsRegion == 'CO') {
        $target = $('#CO3');
    } else {
        $target = $('#none');
    }
    $target.imBannerRotater({
        return_type: 'json',
        data_map: {
            image_name: 'name',
            url_name: 'url'
        },
        image_url: 'http://www.kindreviews.com/wp-content/plugins/geoads/CO3.php',
        base_path: 'http://www.kindreviews.com/wp-content/plugins/geoads/images/',
    });
});
$(function () {
    var $target = $('#CA1');
    if (mmjsRegion == 'CA') {
        $target = $('#CA1');
    } else {
        $target = $('#none');
    }
    $target.imBannerRotater({
        return_type: 'json',
        data_map: {
            image_name: 'name',
            url_name: 'url'
        },
        image_url: 'http://www.kindreviews.com/wp-content/plugins/geoads/CA1.php',
        base_path: 'http://www.kindreviews.com/wp-content/plugins/geoads/images/',
    });
});
$(function () {
    var $target = $('#CA2');
    if (mmjsRegion == 'CA') {
        $target = $('#CA2');
    } else {
        $target = $('#none');
    }
    $target.imBannerRotater({
        return_type: 'json',
        data_map: {
            image_name: 'name',
            url_name: 'url'
        },
        image_url: 'http://www.kindreviews.com/wp-content/plugins/geoads/CA2.php',
        base_path: 'http://www.kindreviews.com/wp-content/plugins/geoads/images/',
    });
});
$(function () {
    var $target = $('#CA3');
    if (mmjsRegion == 'CA') {
        $target = $('#CA3');
    } else {
        $target = $('#none');
    }
    $target.imBannerRotater({
        return_type: 'json',
        data_map: {
            image_name: 'name',
            url_name: 'url'
        },
        image_url: 'http://www.kindreviews.com/wp-content/plugins/geoads/CA3.php',
        base_path: 'http://www.kindreviews.com/wp-content/plugins/geoads/images/',
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var r = mmjsRegion,
    s = r == 'CO' ? '#CO1, #CO2, #CO3' : r == 'CA' ? '#CA1, #CA2, #CA3' : '';

$(s).each(function() {
    $(this).imBannerRotater({
        return_type: 'json',
        data_map: {
            image_name: 'name',
            url_name: 'url'
        },
        image_url: 'http://www.kindreviews.com/wp-content/plugins/geoads/' + this.id + '.php',
        base_path: 'http://www.kindreviews.com/wp-content/plugins/geoads/images/',
    });
});
```

Comment: this also worked, and is simpler.  So i reaccepted this as the answer.

Comment: @zeemy Consider just using CSS classes. For instance, the first group of elements could have a `ca` class, and the second group a `co` class. Then you could just do this: `$('.' + mmjsRegion)` to select the right elements (you wouldn't need to define a `s` variable, like I do in my code).

Answer (score 2):

```
$(["CO;CO1", "CO;CO2", "CO;CO3", "CA;CA1", "CA;CA2", "CA;CA3"]).each(function() {

      var data = this.split(";");
      var id = data[1];
      var region = data[0];

      var $target  = $("#" + id);
      if ( mmjsRegion == region ){
        $target = $("#" + id);
      }
      else{
          $target = $('#none');
        }

      $target.imBannerRotater({
        return_type: 'json',
        data_map: {
          image_name: 'name',
          url_name: 'url'
        },
        image_url: 'http://www.kindreviews.com/wp-content/plugins/geoads/' + id + '.php',
        base_path: 'http://www.kindreviews.com/wp-content/plugins/geoads/images/',
      });

});
```

I dont see the reason of this..

```
var $target  = $('#CO1');
      if ( mmjsRegion == 'CO' ){
        $target = $('#CO1');
      }
      else{
          $target = $('#none');
        }
```

Comment: ya, I did it, because I couldn't figure out how else to write else do not run function.

thanks for the reply!  Sadly, It didn't work when I input it into the site.

Answer (score 2):

Right, I think that can come down to:

```
(function($) {
    $.each(['CO1', 'CO2', 'CO3', 'CA1', 'CA2', 'CA3'], function(index, id) {
        $('#' + (mmjsRegion == id.replace(/\d+$/,'') ? id : 'none')).imBannerRotater({
            return_type: 'json',
            data_map: {
                image_name: 'name',
                url_name: 'url'
            },
            image_url: 'http://www.kindreviews.com/wp-content/plugins/geoads/' + id + '.php',
            base_path: 'http://www.kindreviews.com/wp-content/plugins/geoads/images/',
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

As `mmjsRegion` does not alter during the code, it can come down even more, but I have no idea whether the `imBannerRotate()` plugin is supposed to be called on `$('#none')` three times, looks like a hack.  If the `$('#none')` is not required then it can be:

```
(function($) {
    $.each(['1', '2', '3'], function(index, id) {
        $('#' + mmjsRegion + id).imBannerRotater({
            return_type: 'json',
            data_map: {
                image_name: 'name',
                url_name: 'url'
            },
            image_url: 'http://www.kindreviews.com/wp-content/plugins/geoads/' + mmjsRegion + id + '.php',
            base_path: 'http://www.kindreviews.com/wp-content/plugins/geoads/images/',
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: yeah! why i didn´t look inside of this too

Comment: Sadly this snippet didn't work. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: @Orbling Consider using a regular for loop and then using `i+1`. That should be far more efficient.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: I was aiming for succinctness and a general jQuery feel, rather than performance; the gain would be relatively negligible over 3 iterations.

Comment: I input the code into the wordpress header, and the divs weren't selected. The jquery didn't do anything. You're code looks great. I'm beginning to break it down to understand how you made it. I'd love to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: @zeemy23: There is probably some minor bug, it is hard writing the code without running it.  There's not much too it, just a loop, look for JS errors, or just retain bleepzter code if it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){

    var targets = ['CO', 'CA'];
    var iterations = 3;

    $.each(targets, function(index, value){

        for(var i=1; i<=iterations; i++)
        {
            var targetId = '#' + value + i.toString();
            $target = $(targetId);

            if (mmjsRegion == value) {
                $target = $(targetId);
            } else {
                $target = $('#none');
            }

            $target.imBannerRotater({
                return_type: 'json',
                data_map: {
                    image_name: 'name',
                    url_name: 'url'
                },
                image_url: 'http://www.kindreviews.com/wp-content/plugins/geoads/' + value + i.toString() + '.php',
                base_path: 'http://www.kindreviews.com/wp-content/plugins/geoads/images/'
            });

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: 1. It would make more sense to first check whether `mmjsRegion` is `CO` or `CA` and then only apply the banner stuff to the corresponding elements. 2. The `$target` variable should be declared. 3. You don't need toString() on the `i` variable - it coerces to string automatically. 4. The if-else statement makes no sense. You already assigned `$(targetId)` to `$target` and now you are doing it again?